# Unable to remove elements from chosen select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I'm using chosen.js for multiple select.  When I click close the element is not removed from the select box.  Here is a screen shot for better understanding.

[image]

When I click close on "No Filter" the option in the drop down is getting enabled to reselect it but the element is not removed from the select box.  Help will be highly appreciated.

Hope my question is clear and thanks is anticipation.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Do you mean that you want all the selected items to be un-selected when u click "No Filter"?

Comment: Nope.  When I click 'x' mark that should go off from the box right?  That is how the plugin works.  But in my case when I click 'x' the element is not disappearing from the box.

Comment: Sounds like a browser issue, or maybe jquery version

Comment: Okay.  Let me check with latest jquery version.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.6.  As per documentation it is supported > 1.4.